Powershell Script Not Populating Body Of Encrypted Outlook Email
I am writing a script that will open an encrypted Outlook Template File to send and encrypted email. However, the body of the email is not popluating. Code below. Any help would be appreciated.
    $outlook = New-Object -ComObject outlook.application
    $Mail=$outlook.CreateItemFromTemplate(“C:\Users$env:UserName\AppData\
    Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Encrypted.oft”)
    $Mail.SentOnBehalfOfName = “UnattendedEmailAddress”
    $Mail.To =“VendorEmailAddress”
    $Mail.CC = “HelpDeskEmailAddress”
    $Mail.Subject = “User With The Email $Vendor Was Not Found”
    $Mail.Body = ‘Please Double Check The Vendors Email Address And Then Enter It Again’
    $Mail.save()
    $inspector=$Mail.getinspector
    $inspector.display()
    #$Mail.Send()

Pic of What Email Looks Like 
I have tried to change the format of the body to HTML but no avail.  I tried to use the replace function to replace the blank body with text.

The message needs to be encrypted after it is modified.
Use unencrypted template and set the PR_SECURITY_FLAGS MAPI property using MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty after you set body:
See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dvespa/2009/03/16/how-to-sign-or-encrypt-a-message-programmatically-from-oom/ for an example.

I want to use the IRM encryption built in to O365 and not a third party cert.  Is this possible?

Try to set Permission / PermissionService / PermissionTemplateGuid properties - you can see their value on an existing message in OutlookSpy (I am its author, click Item button).

I used your Outlook Spy and was able to find my PermissionTemplateGUID.  When I set that and the permission property to 3 I was able to get it to work.  Thanks agian.
